# Add map object to Vector in(c++) cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

This is the vector where i want to add map objects

```
  std::vector<cocos2d::Value> optionButton = std::vector<cocos2d::Value>();


 for (int i = 0; i < answerButton.size(); i++)
{
    value = answerButton.at(i).getDescription();

    if(strcmp(value.c_str()," ") == 0)
    {
        CCLOG("Space Detected %s", "Space Detected");

    }
    else
    {
        std::map<std::string ,std::string> keyval;
        keyval["letter"] = value;
        keyval["is_actual"]= "true";

        optionButton.push_back(keyval);            
    }
```

i want to add "keyval"object to "optionButton" vector. is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

Please verify if this works?

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map> optionButton = std::vector<std::unordered_map>();
for (int i = 0; i < answerButton.size(); i++){
  value = answerButton.at(i).getDescription();

  if(strcmp(value.c_str()," ") == 0) CCLOG("Space Detected %s", "Space Detected");
  else {
    std::unordered_map<std::string ,std::string> keyval;
    keyval["letter"] = value;
    keyval["is_actual"]= "true";

    optionButton.push_back(keyval);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `std::unordered_map` instead.

From [the reference](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Value) :

> `cocos2d::Value` is a wrapper class for many primitives (`int`, `float`,`double`, `bool`, `unsigned char`, `char*` and `std::string`)
>   plus `std::vector<Value>`, `std::unordered_map<std::string,Value>` and
>   `std::unordered_map<int,Value>`.

You don't have to change your code much.

I didn't try but I think this should work (entirely based on what I quoted) :

```
// ...
std::unordered_map<std::string, cocos2d::Value> keyval;
keyval["letter"] = value;     // I don't know what type is value
keyval["is_actual"] = "true"; // Implicit conversion

optionButton.push_back(keyval);
// ...
```